# having trouble creating multiple dynamic dropdown filter in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm new to PHP and I am creating a bank ifsc code generator. I have the sql file which contains two table:

**table 1**:

```sql
`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `bank_names`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `bank_names` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=228 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;`
```

and **table 2**:

```sql
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `data`;
/*!40101 SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client */;
/*!40101 SET character_set_client = utf8 */;
CREATE TABLE `data` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(300) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ifsc` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `adr1` text,
  `adr2` text,
  `adr3` text,
  `adr4` text,
  `adr5` text,
  `contact` text,
  `date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `micr` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=153838 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I want to create something like this on the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GUgo.png)

I need a multiple dynamic dropdown that show data according to previous selected table columns.